# Knockout: Removing element from an array inside of another array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of items. Each of these items has an array of children. Each of the children has an array of grandchildren. I want to allow removal of grandchildren.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/FMWMR/18/

What should go into removeGrandchild function? Thank you.

Comment: Here is the updated link related to my question: http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/tAuUk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I wrote for your `removeGrandchild` function:

```
    removeGrandchild = function(data, event) {
        var context = ko.contextFor(event.currentTarget);
        var dataGrandchild = context.$data;
        var parentItemChild = context.$parent;

        var grandchildToRemove = 
            ko.utils.arrayFirst(parentItemChild.grandchildren(), 
                                function(grandchild) {
            return (grandchild.name() === dataGrandchild.name());
        });
        var indexOfGrandchildToRemove = 
            ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(parentItemChild.grandchildren(), 
                                  grandchildToRemove);
        if (indexOfGrandchildToRemove >= 0) {
            parentItemChild.grandchildren.splice(indexOfGrandchildToRemove, 1);
        }
    };
```

*[Pardon the goofy formatting... just trying to avoid horizontal scrolling.]*

Take particular note of the first three lines of the function, as `ko.contextFor` is an important feature that came about in the 2.0.0 release of Knockout, and you'll likely find that this will come in handy a lot while working with knockout.

Finally, here's my forked fiddle with my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/U6dc7/

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. This resolves my problem. I will definitely review ko.contextFor.